# 7 почти одинаковых запросов тормозят скрипт

Tags: оптимизация, mysql

Доброго всем здравия.
Делал, делал и получил 30 минутную работу скрипта :(
В БД таблица, там товар($X1), а у него 7 складов (A100-А700)

Может есть возможность оптимизации вот этого.

Может что-то универсальнее в SQL-запросах есть, чего я не знаю пока. Чем этот перебор UPDATE'ом по семи строкам?

```
$result1 = mysql_query ("UPDATE $table SET $table.field_01='$A1', $table.field_02='$B1' WHERE $table.field_04='A100' and $table.field_05='$X'", $db);
$result2 = mysql_query ("UPDATE $table SET $table.field_01='$A2', $table.field_02='$B2' WHERE $table.field_04='A200' and $table.field_05='$X'", $db);
$result3 = mysql_query ("UPDATE $table SET $table.field_01='$A3', $table.field_02='$B3' WHERE $table.field_04='A300' and $table.field_05='$X'", $db);
$result4 = mysql_query ("UPDATE $table SET $table.field_01='$A4', $table.field_02='$B4' WHERE $table.field_04='A400' and $table.field_05='$X'", $db);
$result5 = mysql_query ("UPDATE $table SET $table.field_01='$A5', $table.field_02='$B5' WHERE $table.field_04='A500' and $table.field_05='$X'", $db);
$result6 = mysql_query ("UPDATE $table SET $table.field_01='$A6', $table.field_02='$B6' WHERE $table.field_04='A600' and $table.field_05='$X'", $db);
$result7 = mysql_query ("UPDATE $table SET $table.field_01='$A7', $table.field_02='$B7' WHERE $table.field_04='A700' and $table.field_05='$X'" $db);
```

Слишком уж это место мне самому, как-то, не нравится...
P.S. Чуток исправил, там где $X (он приходит 1, на 7 записей, потом другой, на следующие 7)

Comment: У вас есть поле **field_05** или **field_04** уникальным?

Comment: нет. обычные.
Именно, что они повторяются по 7 раз на каждый товар(который тоже отражён, как 7 одинаковых записей ID кода)

Comment: @I_CaR, там для комментов места уже нет )) В общем, в том запросе, который вы показали есть ошибочки. Названия полей таблицы оборачиваются в обратные кавычки (англ. раскладка, буква "Ё"), а данные, которые вносятся в БД обёрнуты правильно - в одинарные кавычки. Плюс ко всему, повторюсь, что запрос будет работать только, если поле, в вашем примере, *Sklad_ID* или поле *ItemID* будет, как уникальный или первичный ключ.

Comment: про ошибку со знаком (`), я сразу заметил при первом тесте. А вот с полями потруднее, как они могут стать уникальными, если они повторяются? В той таблице, уникальное др.поле "message_id" Каким способом этот запрос за него завязать? Если данные на это поле вообще не приходят. т.е. их нет вообще в XML и это поле, просто поле-счётчик.

вот тут почитал: http://www.askdev.ru/mysql/9421/как-работает-ON-DUPLICATE-KEY-UPDATE/new/#answer16935
там запрос завязан за UID, уникальное поле. Но мои поля в запросе, и с приходящими данными от XML, не уникальны :(

Comment: Сделал связку
ALTER TABLE message219_for_test ADD UNIQUE key_unique (Sklad_ID, ItemID)  
выдернул значения ключевого поля Message_ID и заюзал это через запрос:  
http://www.tavil.ru/netcat/tmp/code_2.html

И опять нуль-результата...  
Связка же (склад-id_товара) есть, почему не фурычит?  
И по первому не фурычит, http://www.tavil.ru/netcat/tmp/code.html и по второму (с захватом ключевого поля) http://www.tavil.ru/netcat/tmp/code_2.html.  И ошибок не выдаёт, может в запросе, что не так? Данные в переменные приходят, названия полей перепроверил.

Comment: УРА!!! Заработало!!!
----------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, на свой вопрос в коменте, боюсь что ответ не дождусь. А если всё-таки у вас или поле **field_04** или **field_05** является **PRIMARY** или **UNIQUE**, то запрос можно составить так:

```
INSERT INTO $table 
    (`field_01`, `field_02`, `field_04`, `field_05` ) 
VALUES 
    ('$A1', '$B1', 'A100', '$X1'), 
    ('$A2', '$B2', 'A200', '$X2'), 
    ('$A3', '$B3', 'A300', '$X3'), 
    ('$A4', '$B4', 'A400', '$X4')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    `field_01` = VALUES(`field_01`) , `field_02` = VALUES(`field_02`)
```

Comment: Врядли эти поля уникальны, иначе бд на 30 минут бы не задумывалась, даже при очень большом объеме.
Кстати да, судя по описанию структуры ключ `UNIQUE` так и просится на связку из полей `field_04` и `field_05`

Comment: @Павел Вершинин, по поводу 30-ти минут, так это преувеличение )) Я не вижу даже в запросах ТС ничего угрожающего. Психанул и запустил 50 таких запросов. Результат - не более 2 секунд. Тормоза могут быть совершенно по другой причине.

Comment: Нет! нет нет!! Они не уникальны, они повторяются по 7 раз на каждый товар(который тоже отражён, как 7 одинаковых записей ID кода)
UNIQUE в той БД вообще на др.поля.
В Вашем коде что-то есть, заманчивое. А почему INSERT, а не UPDATE? Хотя он в будущем тоже потребуется, для внесения новых. Сейчас пока UPDATE на изменения провожу.

Comment: @I_CaR, если вы про мой коментарий, то я имел в виду, что запустил 50 запросов, как у вас. )) Сейчас попсиховал дальше - запустил 100 запросов аналогичных вашим и уже замерял время выполнения. Результат - без одной тысячной, ровно 3 секунды. А у вас то их всего семь. Откуда тормоза - не пойму.

Comment: >  А почему INSERT, а не UPDATE? Хотя он в будущем потребуется тоже, для внесения новых.

Вы до конца досмотрели запрос? )) Фишка в **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**, т.е. если уникальный ключ/ключи совпадают, то INSERT не выполняется, а апдейтится существующая запись.

Comment: @Deonis
На счёт 30 минут нет никакого преувеличения, на локалке делается на 60% быстрее. Запросы, т.е. переменные для них, собираю foreach'ем из XML, тут же в цикле и делал UPDATE.

Comment: @I_CaR, что-то тут не так.

> на локалке делается на 60% быстрее

Я ж дотошный. )) Загнал на хост. И хотите верьте, хотите нет, но на хосте выполнилось быстрее чем на локалке и значительно быстрее. 100 запросов - менее секунды. И на хосте не nginx, который пошустрее, а Apache/2.2.14

Comment: Я же тоже, пока не сделаю, не умру ;)
Про ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, почитал сразу.
Пробую... Please WAIT
-----
P.S. на локалке при отключении этих UPDATE'ов время 0,02 сек
при включении - 9,83 сек.
-----
поменял запрос на Ваш, но как-то ни ошибок, ни изменений в БД.
сделал так:
http://tavil.ru/netcat/tmp/code.html

Comment: 10 раз проверил тестилкой скорости, на локалке 10 сек, на сервере 30сек.
---
И самое непонятное, делаю простой UPDATE одного поля на таблицу 50 000(!) раз и время, всего, занимает 30 сек., строк в ней около 1600. А в таблице с которой работаю сейчас, строк около 24 000. Но мне кажется дело не в количестве строк в таблице, а во вложенном foreach в foreach для переменных.

Comment: А то, что, эти 2 поля с точностью 15 знаков после запятой (DOUBLE) не может влиять?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы добавил `LOW_PRIORITY` в запросы. 
И наверно индекс на поля `field_04` и `field_05`

Comment: в ОС LOW_PRIORITY на процессы наоборот замедляет их выполнение (возьмите например winrar).
А в выполнении команды UPDATE это даст + ?

Comment: Ну скажем так, с `LOW_PRIORITY` фактическое выполнение запроса будет отложено до тех пор пока БД не станет посвободней. Тобишь запрос встанет в очередь, а скрипт пойдет дальше.
Но забудьте об этом, вам Deonis дал замечательный совет, намного лучше моего. Только сделайте ваши записи уникальными, что-то типа:

ALTER TABLE  `table` ADD UNIQUE  `UNIQUE` ( `field_04`, `field_05`)

У вас ведь наверняка один и тот-же товар не может повторяться в пределах одного склада?

Comment: Про уникальность я и понял при ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, но как зауникалить поле, которое повторяется? Уникальные поля разве повторятся могут? Товар (ID) повторяется по кол-ву складов. А склады в свою очередь повторяются в строке другого уже товара.

Comment: У вас связка из полей склад+товар может повторятся? 
Думаю что нет. Поэтому предлагаю повесить `unique` ключ НЕ на одно поле, а на оба вместе склад+товар

ALTER TABLE  `test` ADD UNIQUE  `key_unique` (`field_04`, `field_05`)

Comment: Сделал связку
ALTER TABLE message219_for_test ADD UNIQUE key_unique (Sklad_ID, ItemID)

выделнул значения ключевого поля Message_ID и заюзал это через запрос:
http://www.tavil.ru/netcat/tmp/code_2.html

И опять нуль-результата...

Comment: Я конечно могу ошибаться, сам редко пользуюсь подобным видом запросов, а гуглить нет времени, ухожу. Но помоему запрос немного неверен. Мне кажется правильно так: http://pastebin.com/8PDhjsVT
Изменил последнюю строку запроса

Comment: INSERT INTO $userstable3 SET(<- !!!) ВОТ ОНА - ОШИБКА!!!!!
SET НЕ НУЖНО ТАМ!!!
И всё!!! Заработало!!!  
Специально Спасибо! @Павел Вершинин, и @Deonis!!!